# What is the use of Python property decorator that returns an instance?

Tags: python, properties, tornado

I saw a code as follows (from https://github.com/daydayfree/diggit/blob/master/model/model.py) :

```
from database import Database
...
class Model(object):
    @property
    def db(self): return Database()

    def insert(self, documents):
        return self.db.insert(self.table, documents)
...
```

The main aim for `@property` is to provide access to the methods in `Database()` instance, am I correct?

So can I rewrite it as:

```
from database import Database
...
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = Database()

    def insert(self, documents):
        return self.db.insert(self.table, documents)
```

and

```
from database import Database
...
class Model(object):
    def db(self):
        return Database()

    def insert(self, documents):
        return self.db().insert(self.table, documents)
...
```

? If not, what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences...

Method 1: property decorator

```
class Model(object):
    @property
    def db(self): return Database() 

o = Model()
db1 = o.db  #a database instance. No brackets
db2 = o.db  #another database instance
o.db = foo  #error due to read only property
```

Every time db is called it creates a new database instance.

Method 2: db set on initialization

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = Database()

o = Model()
db1 = o.db  #a database instance
db2 = o.db  #the same database instance
o.db = foo  #works fine so long as foo is defined
```

Every time db is accessed it returns the same database instance.

Method 3: db as a function

```
class Model(object):
    def db(self):
        return Database()

o = Model()
db1 = o.db()  #a database instance. note the brackets
db2 = o.db()  #another database instance
o.db = foo    #works fine so long as foo is defined
```

Every time db is called it creates a new database instance.

Answer (score 1):

The `@property` decorator is used to make calling a method look like calling an instance.

So, if you had a `Model` instance, you could get a **new** database object by calling the `db` what looks like the `db` attribute, but is really the `db` method:

```
>>> a = Model()
>>> a.db
Database()
```

In your first "rewrite" example, you create a `db` attribute in the `__init__` method of your class.  Now, every time you call the `db` attribute, you will get the **same** `Database` object each time (the one created during the `__init__` call), not a **new**  one as before.

To imagine this, you could replace `return Database()` with `return random.random()` from the python standard library.  In the original implementation, a new number will be returned each time you call `db`.  In your suggested implementation, the same number will be returned each time because `random.random()` was only called once (in the `__init__` method), and it's output was saved in `db`.

Your second "rewrite" is essentially the same as the original implementation, except that you would call `db` as a method (i.e. with the open and close parentheses).

```
>>> a = Model()
>>> a.db()
Database()
```

Comment: +1 for the "random". But I like Sheena's answer more because it is clearer. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new Database instance when it is called similar to your second alternative. This means every call to `insert` creates a new Database instance, inserts and then deletes the Database instance because there is no reference left pointing to it.

In your first alternative you will always acess the same instance. This means after a call to insert, the Database object is still there.

Comment: So can I rewrite it as the way I mentioned? Are there any differences? They all create an Database Instance